# Meaning of "Ein guter Ruf verpflichtet"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I have seen this sentence below in a text where the speaker is talking about respecting the elderly. I can't say I understand this sentence.

> Ein guter Ruf verpflichtet

Comment: And then there’s *ist der Ruf erst ruiniert, lebt’s sich gänzlich ungeniert* ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you have a good reputation, and you have to act accordingly to preserve it. So, having a good reputation obliges you to be well-behaved, otherwise you'd lose it.

Similarly, there is a saying "Adel verpflichtet", which expresses the same idea with regards to the aristocracy.

Comment: "Adel verpflichtet" means "noblesse oblige" in English. Err, French. Or both?

Comment: @Robert Indeed! / In der Tat.